# Display html body retrieved from gmail api

Tags: php, html, css, email, gmail-api

I'm working on synchronization between gmail account and CRM system. By synchronization I mean retrieving all gmail messages and store them in DB. A user may read these emails in the CRM.

So, I've parsed gmail api response, stored html bodies in DB and now I try to display them. However the html formed by gmail itself, for example, there are some classes of gmail, plus the very very big quote-history (like when you've responded multiple times to the same letter). Also since some messages contain the whole new html page (for example some kind of advertising), eventually it breaks my own styling.

I think I'm doing it wrong when I simply displaying email HTML body in a div. But how should I do it? Preferably I also want to hide the quotation-part with a lot of `<blockquote>` tags.

Basically I display the messages in the feed which consists of array of bootstrap panels, and inside the panel-body I want to have a subject and nicely-formatted email body

Comment: The easiest approach would be to display the body in an iframe. That way the message styles and the surrounding page styles don't interfere.

Comment: Oh thanks, yes I've tried to display the messages in iframe. However since there are a lot of emails it's a quite slow action. For example 20-30 iframes are slow. But anyway it's kind of solution, plus I can show an iframe only when user asks for it (like put a "Show" button or something). But you know, I've checked the html body of email in getbase.com CRM, and the HTML differs from the one I got in gmail account. I've synced my gmail with getbase and checked html of my emails in google mailbox and in getbase, and it looks like they change the HTML somehow...

Comment: Also I've checked another CRM, and again it looks like they have their own HTML email body. But I can't figure out how it's possible, since when I get an HTML from gmail I got as well their classes like "gmail-quote" or "gmail-extra". But at the same time not everything that I can see by using chrome developer tools. For example, how can I add a button which hides quoted text? Of course I can somehow parse html body, find "gmail-quote" class and add some html before it, but this is very clumsy and ugly solution

Comment: I am facing the same issue. I tried with the approach here. https://github.com/nylas/nylas-mail/blob/master/packages/client-app/src/services/quoted-html-transformer.es6 

But not working. If you find a solution, please let us know.